# What are these custom declarations in this C program?

Tags: c, declaration, variable-declaration

I have a very simple question, what are these declarations in the beginning of this C program called? Normally in a C program you list the `<variable-type>` `<variable-name>`, and optionally the `<variable-value>`. But in the first few lines of this program it seems it goes; `<random-word>` `<variable-name>`;

what is this syntax called? So I can learn more about it..

```
#include<X11/Xlib.h>

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    Display *dpy;
    Window rootwin;
    Window win;
    Colormap cmap;
    XEvent e;
    int scr;
    GC gc;
```

Comment: Ever considered those random words might be types defined in Xlib.h?

Comment: Those are types defined within the Xlib.h header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're simply types defined in the `X11/Xlib.h` header file, the main head file for Xlib. It's the one you include when you want everything.

For example, under Debian, the `Xlib.h` file contains:

```
typedef struct _XDisplay Display;
```

after defining a (rather large) `struct _XDisplay`.

Comment: `typedef` that was the word I was looking for. I didn't know what it was called. Thank you.